# How can I see how many people used the facebook recommendations box using fb_ref?

Tags: facebook, google-analytics, facebook-like, facebook-recommendations

I'm trying to see how successful my facebook recommendations box truly is. I've added the fb_ref attribute to the box but where can I get the number of people who actually clicked on links through that box?

Bonus: Is there a way in GA to check against the url parameter?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the fb_ref parameter documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/recommendations/

Since the page is served up from your web server, this parameter can be analyzed by your web servers' logs or even GA.

For GA, here's an interesting read about query string parameters and how GA deals with them.

http://iqcontent.com/blog/2007/06/dealing-with-query-strings-in-google-analytics/

http://cutroni.com/blog/2006/09/21/google-analytics-configuration-mistake-2-query-string-variables/

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Analytics/thread?tid=15b7b8681b313231&hl=en

Comment: Amazing thank you so much. There's no way to get the numbers via insights or graph api by any chance? The reason I ask is cause I want to see the past data, the GA trick is great for going forward.